# Не создаются модули

Tags: lua, steam-web-api, модули, steam

Недавно изучаю lua. Нашел библиотеку steamweb-sdk, там не много файлов но в каждом есть подобная строка 
`module( "steamwebapi" )` , на которую lua ругается таким образом.

```
lua: ./steamwebapi.lua:11: attempt to call a nil value (global 'module')
stack traceback:
        ./steamwebapi.lua:11: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        test/login.lua:9: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Оказывается даже на файл с таким наполнением:

```
module("test")
```

lua отвечает:

```
lua: ./test/tst.lua:2: attempt to call a nil value (global 'module')
stack traceback:
        ./test/tst.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

*Я использую Lua5.3 
 
 на одном сайте прочитал такие слова:*

```
Старый способ создания модулей:    
В Lua 5.0 and 5.1 есть функция module, которая используется таким образом:
```

*В общем быстренько поставил Lua5.1 

 вот два наглядных скрина:*
[image: lua5.1 win]
[image: lua5.3 nix]

***Может кто то объяснить почему так?***

Comment: Видимо, `module` где-то определён. Поскольку на гитхабе этого модуля больше нет (по всей видимости), определение показать не могу, да и вообще пользоваться этим поостерёгся бы в пользу чего-нибудь более обобщённо-HTTP-API'шного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module` не работает начиная с Lua 5.2 (в 5.2 он ещё определён, не не работает). Перепишите код используя новый механизм окружений (`_ENV` в помощь), или возьмите другую библиотеку.